# HTML & Javascript blackjack game will not display winners and hands

Tags: javascript, html, output, blackjack

I'm trying to develop a blackjack game using JavaScript and HTML.

I've tested it using JavaScript alone on REPL and it worked fine, I've now tried to move it over to a html page so that I can eventually add in some graphics.

However when I run the code below none of the players hands, house hand or the winner appear on the screen, but the prompts do.

Can anyone see an issue with this?

```js
function play() {
  playersQ = prompt('How many people are playing?');
  playershands = [];
  i = 0;
  count = 0;
  var player_cards = 0;

  function player() {
    var player_cards = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) + 1;
    while (player_cards < 21) {
      Hit = prompt('Players cards are ' + player_cards + ' Would you like stick or twist?(S/T)')
      if (Hit == 'T') {
        player_cards = player_cards + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
      } else if (Hit == 'S') {
        break;
      } else if (player_cards > 21) {
        alert('Player is bust');
        break;
      }
    }
    return player_cards;
  }

  function house() {
    var house_cards = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) + 1;
    document.getElementById('housecurrenthand').innerHTML = ('House has ' + house_cards);
    while (house_cards < 18) {
      house_cards = house_cards + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
      document.getElementById('housecurrenthand').innerHTML = ('House has ' + house_cards);
      if (house_cards > 21) {
        alert('House is bust')
      }
    }
    return house_cards;
  }

  while (i < playersQ) {
    playershands.push(player());
    i = i + 1;
  }

  var house_hand = house();

  while (count < playersQ) {
    count2 = count + 1
    if (playershands[count] > house_hand && playershands[count] < 22) {
      document.getElementById('playershand' + [i]).innerHTML = ('Player ' + count2 + ' has ' + playershands[count]);
      document.getElementById('winner').innerHTML = ('Player wins');
      count = count + 1;
    } else if (house_hand > playershands[count] && house_hand < 22) {
      document.getElementById('househand').innerHTML = ('House has' + house_hand);
      document.getElementById('winner').innerHTML = ('House wins');
      break;
    } else if (house_hand == playershands[count]) {
      document.getElementById('winner').innerHTML = ('draw');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <h1 align="center">21 Game</h1>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#458B00">
  <div align='center'>
    <h3>House Cards</h3>
    <h5 id='currenthousehand'></h5>
    <h5 id='househand'> </h5>

    <h3>Players Cards</h3>
    <h5 id='playershand1'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand2'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand3'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand4'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand5'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand6'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand7'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand8'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand9'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand10'> </h5>

    <h4 id='winner'> </h4>

    <button onclick="play()" float='bottom'>Play</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why `playershand + [i]` instead of `playershand + i`. Also 21 is not really the same as blackjack...

Comment: you are trying innerHTML to a null

Comment: housecurrenthand vs currenthousehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to reach to value of DOM element with ID ***housecurrenthand*** in line 66 line (function house), but in your html file you have declared header with ID ***currenthousehand*** (line 12).

If you are not using Google Chrome I encourage you to try it out. When your press **F12** there is developer tool that will help you to find out where the problem is.

Check official documentation for [Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), where is a lot of information how to debug your web code. If you are using any other browser just look for documentation or tutorials how to handle issue like current one.

Comment: If using chrome... Or IE or Edge or FireFox